# oscommerce / loadedcommerce code compilation

Tags: php, oscommerce

I am not very experienced with Loaded Commerce which I believe is just an updated version of OScommerce?

However, I wanted to add additional information to the order email so I found the code and edited the file I believe built the email: checkout_process.php.

I added in 2 lines of code and it appeared to work as expected - my emails were now containing the extra information.

Side Note: I have had a problem recently (which I don't think is related but will add for additional context) where the web server reached capacity and shutdown.  I cleaned it out and restarted and all was fine.

My Problem: the last 2 email orders that have been received have dropped the information I added.  I have gone back into the file and the code is still there - everything surrounding it is being included except the code I added.

I simply "touched" the file so that it had a last modified date of today, tested the process again and voilà! The information is back again, appearing as expected!

Can anyone explain how this could possibly happen? Perhaps Loaded Commerce operates on compiled version of the code which somehow reverted?

While the problem is fixed now, I'd really like to understand what could possibly have happened to cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Founder of Loaded Commerce here.

the caching is not a code issue, its a php server issue. I'm no PHP/Apache expert but I do know that 6.x of Loaded Commerce does not have any compiled code from us in it.

Sounds like touching the file simply caused Apache to reload it. Or something.

6.x is old code. Loaded 7 which is based on osc 3 Alpha 5 includes the vqmod hook system from open cart. please take a look at how we handle addons in that www.loaded7.com its in beta at the moment. the docs.loaded7.com has documenation on how to make a custom code hook.

Comment: It turns out there are 2 independent order emails - 1 for general purchases and one for paypal.  I didn't realise that there is a paypal file that does almost exactly everything that checkout_process does from an order confirmation perspective!

Comment: However, i cannot figure out where the paypal tax is configured: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644954/loadedcommerce-tax-display-issue