# loadedcommerce tax display issue

Tags: php, content-management-system, oscommerce

In my installation of loadedcommerce I have it all running and configured as I like it.

I have configured the tax as follows:

`Display Prices with Tax = true`

On the website = perfect - prices appear Tax Inclusive

In emails generated via Direct Debit Payment Process = perfect - prices appear Tax Inclusive

In emails generated via Paypal Payment Process - fail - prices appear Tax Exclusive

Can anyone advise where the Paypal settings are for tax and pricing?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a b2b site, this can also be affected by settings in Customers -> Customer Groups.  I've seen some indication recently that the Paypal modules may not respect group settings correctly..